# Running head ieee transactions

Tags: ieeetran

I am using overleaf to write IEEE Transaction paper. The problem I am facing is with the running head. Check the following line:

```
\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Reliability}{Jia \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: A Novel Tin Can Link}
```

Ideally, The first part should appear on the first page and later on even pages at top left corner, while the second part should appear at top right corner on odd pages.

In my case, only the first part appears, that too on every page in the top right corner. What might the problem be?

I am using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelsep=newline}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm{} \thealgorithm:}
\makeatother

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%

  \item[\bfseries

  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Abbreviations}{%

  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Notations}{}}%

]}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Access Points Optimization}

\author{ Abc~def,~\IEEEmembership{Senior Member,~IEEE, }
hij, Qrs, ~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE, } lmn op, ~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE, } Yz wxy
        % <-this % stops a space

\thanks{Manuscript received Month XX, 20XX; revised XX XX, 20XX.}

\thanks{This work was supported by the.}

\thanks{(Corresponding author: )}

\thanks{Authors are with the Research Center, School of .}}

\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Reliability}{Jia \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: A Novel Tin Can Link}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're presumably using the `IEEEtran` document class because you wish to get a paper published with one of the journals that require/encourage the use of this document class. If that's the case, I would *under no circumstance* mess with design elements of the journal -- such as what material shows up in the header line. Please advise if I've misinterpreted your setup.

Comment: @Mico I have been using IEEE trans template from overleaf... what i observed few other things beside the running head were also different from what i saw from already published papers. I made the changes in the template so it can match the already accepted papers format. e.g. like tables, figures captions etc.. i think this issue can also be resolved if someone knows about any specific line to add,remove or modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have two issues here:

1. If you have to submit an article to an journal asked to use class `IEEEtran` with option `journal` you should not change the given layout of that wished class.  If there are differences in the layout of your article you can print to the layout of the journal, it is the work of the journal to prepare your article to fit there layout -- it is **not** your task! 
   If you have not to submit an article I'm not sure you are allowed to use this class (check the licenze for this!). Better would be to use another class ...
2. The command `\maekboth{}{}` can only work, if your document is printed twoside. That is not given if you use `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`. If you realy need to get this to work you can add option `twoside` to `\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}`.

Please see the following corrected MWE (I only added `twoside` and deleted some not needed packages and commands for this issue, also the double called package `booktabs` (do not do this!) and changed the order of packages and commands in the preamble):

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran} % <===========================

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Abbreviations}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Notations}{}}%
]}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelsep=newline}
\makenomenclature


\begin{document}

\title{Access Points Optimization}

\author{ Abc~def,~\IEEEmembership{Senior Member,~IEEE, }
hij, Qrs, ~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE, } lmn op, ~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE, } Yz wxy
        % <-this % stops a space

\thanks{Manuscript received Month XX, 20XX; revised XX XX, 20XX.}
\thanks{This work was supported by the.}
\thanks{(Corresponding author: )}
\thanks{Authors are with the Research Center, School of .}}

\markboth{IEEE Transactions on Reliability}{Jia \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: A Novel Tin Can Link}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract 
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract 
\end{abstract}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and its resulting page 3:

[image: resulting page 3]